# Size of managed structures

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

The .NET 4.0 Framework introduces classes for [reading and writing memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(VS.100).aspx). The classes are centred around methods for [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294202(VS.100).aspx) and [writing structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294099(VS.100).aspx). These are not marshalled but copied from and to the file in the form in which they are laid out in managed memory.

Let's say I want to write two structures sequentially to a memory mapped file using these methods:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Foo
{
    public char C;
    public bool B;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Bar
{
}

static void Write<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    where T1 : struct
    where T2 : struct
{
    using (MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, 32))
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor())
    {
        accessor.Write<T1>(0L, ref item1);  //  <-- (1)
        accessor.Write<T2>(??, ref item2);  //  <-- (2)
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo { C = 'α', B = true };
    Bar bar = new Bar { };
    Write(foo, bar);
}
```

How would I get the number of bytes written in (1) so I can write the next value adjacently in (2)?

*Note: The number of bytes in the example is 3(=2+1), not 5(=1+4) as returned by Marshal.SizeOf.*

*Note 2: `sizeof` cannot determine the size of generic type parameters.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no documented/public way to access the internal `SizeOfType` function used by the `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` class, so the most practical way of getting the size of those structures would be to use reflection like this:

```
static readonly Func<Type, uint> SizeOfType = (Func<Type, uint>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Type, uint>), typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("SizeOfType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));

static void Write<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    where T1 : struct
    where T2 : struct
{
    using (MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, 32))
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor())
    {
        accessor.Write(0, ref item1);
        accessor.Write(SizeOfType(typeof(T1)), ref item2);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. I was hoping for a cleaner solution. Relying on internal, undocumented methods is not a really good idea IMO.

Comment: In my experience it's often good enough (at least in server applications) and furthermore, it's usually the only way of doing that particular thing in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Emit to access the Sizeof opcode and bypass compiler's restriction on getting sizeof(T):

```
var sizeOfMethod = new DynamicMethod(
    "GetManagedSizeImpl"
,   typeof(uint)
,   null
,   true);
var genSizeOf = sizeOfMethod.GetILGenerator();
genSizeOf.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, typeof(T));
genSizeOf.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var sizeOfFunction = (Func<uint>)sizeOfMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<uint>));

// ...
int size = checked((int)sizeOfFunction());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, извините за беспокойство.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** One answer on this page proposes using the internal function [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof), but this only works for structs which do not contain any managed references. On **.NET 4.7** it throws an `ArgumentException` when passed a reference (`class`) type, or a `struct` type which contains embedded references.

**2.** Another answer here suggests using the [**IL**](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) `sizeof` opcode. This works correctly for all `struct` value types--including generics and those with embedded references--but for reference types it always returns `IntPtr.Size` (*i.e.,* the value `4` or `8`), as opposed to the actual *layout size* of (an instance of) the managed class. This may be what you want, depending on your situation. Note that this sort of result gracefully degrades by conflating the case of a struct containing a single embedded reference (handle) with a single reference (handle) itself.

A simpler way to invoke the `sizeof` IL instruction is via the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Un­safe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) package:

```
int struct_layout_bytes = Unsafe.Sizeof<T>();
```

**3.** If you **truly** need the actual *layout size* of (an instance of) a managed class for some reason, then you're probably doing something wrong, but you can obtain it via the following, which only works for reference types, that is, when `typeof(T).IsValueType` is `false`.

```
int class_layout_bytes = Marshal.ReadInt32(typeof(T).TypeHandle.Value, 4)
```

**4.** Therefore--and still with the preceding caveat--to get the ***instance layout size*** for *any* reference- or value-type--including those containing embedded references--from its `Type` handle, combine methods #2 and #3:

```
int instance_layout_bytes = typeof(T).IsValueType ? 
                                Unsafe.Sizeof<T>() : 
                                Marshal.ReadInt32(typeof(T).TypeHandle.Value, 4);
```

<sub>related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519200/size-of-struct-with-generic-type-fields</sub>