# Writing packed structs with a MemoryMappedViewAccessor bug?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, memory-mapped-files

I have a struct that is defined with `Pack=1` and it is 29 bytes long. If it is not packed, it would be 32 bytes long.

- `Marshal.SizeOf(TypeOf(StructName))` returns 29.
- `StructName struct; sizeof(struct)` returns 32.

When I write that struct out using `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` it writes out 32 bytes, NOT 29 bytes.

So, short of marshalling the struct to a byte array and writing it out that way, is there any way to get it to write out that struct correctly?

More detail: if you use Explicit layout, Write will, in fact, write out 29 bytes. WriteArray, though, writes out 32 bytes for each element.

And **avip**, yes, meticulous byte serializing will probably work, but (and I didn't profile it but I am guessing) it is probably orders of magnitude slower than a WriteArray would be, no?

Comment: Did you define layout attribute S.A [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] ? You have to do that to avoid padding.

Comment: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]  - according to documentation, that should eliminate padding (and does), except neither sizeof nor the MemoryMappedViewAccessor acknowledge that.

The doc for the sequential layout says:

Sequential

The members of the object are laid out sequentially, in the order in which they appear when exported to unmanaged memory. The members are **laid out according to the packing** specified in StructLayoutAttribute.Pack, and can be noncontiguous.

Comment: It is an implementation detail for MMFs, it uses `Marshal.AlignedSizeOf<T>()` regardless of the packing.

Comment: @Hans but the actual memory map is also not packed.

Comment: Erm, the memory map is whatever you make it.  That it is 32 bytes instead of 29 doesn't matter at all unless you try to sub-divide the map and get sub-sections aligned.  Yes, this goes bad with Pack=1, it can't assume that if *one* struct has Pack=1 that all the other ones have it as well.  Always a bad idea to pack like that, the default of 8 is there for a very good reason.  I'd assume the OP was left with a bad choice he couldn't control.  You restated what he already knew, marshal yourself.

Comment: Hans, the reason for tight packing of this struct is that I am going to have millions of them stored in a file. Extra 3 bytes in the struct translates into megabytes of disk space. Also - AlignedSizeOf - where is that documented? I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: OK I finally understood what you're really asking. We usually don'y use `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` to serialize objects, and now you know why.

The following will give you the expected result.

```
public static class ByteSerializer
{
    public static Byte[] Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> msg) where T : struct
    {
        List<byte> res = new List<byte>();
        foreach (var s in msg)
        {
            res.AddRange(Serialize(s));
        }
        return res.ToArray();
    }

    public static Byte[] Serialize<T>(T msg) where T : struct
    {
        int objsize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        Byte[] ret = new Byte[objsize];

        IntPtr buff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objsize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(msg, buff, true);
        Marshal.Copy(buff, ret, 0, objsize);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buff);
        return ret;
    }
}

class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    struct Yours
    {
        public Int64 int1;
        public DateTime dt1;
        public float f1;
        public float f2;
        public float f3;
        public byte b;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var file = @"c:\temp\test.bin";
        IEnumerable<Yours> t = new Yours[3];
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, ByteSerializer.Serialize(t));

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("file size: " + stream.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: So it appears DateTime really likes to be on an aligned memory address. Though you can define the explicit layout, I think a more simple approach would be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Test
{
    private long dt1; 
    public byte b;
    public Int64 int1;
    public float f1;
    public float f2;
    public float f3;

    public DateTime DT
    {
        get { return new DateTime(dt1); }
        set { dt1 = value.Ticks; }
    }
}
```

Though I don't see why you should care about managed memory representation at all.

Alternatively, `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` should prevent memory alignment.

Example (the 'managed sizeof' is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127707/size-of-managed-structures))

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 9)]
public struct Test
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DateTime dt1;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public byte b;
}

class Program
{
    static readonly Func<Type, uint> SizeOfType = (Func<Type, uint>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Type, uint>), typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("SizeOfType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));

    static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test() { dt1 = DateTime.MaxValue, b = 42 };
        Console.WriteLine("Managed size: " + SizeOfType(typeof(Test)));
        Console.WriteLine("Unmanaged size: " + Marshal.SizeOf(t));
        using (MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, 1))
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = file.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            accessor.Write(0L, ref t);
            long pos = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                Console.Write("|" + accessor.ReadByte(pos++));
            Console.Write("|\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Managed size: 9
Unmanaged size: 9
|255|63|55|244|117|40|202|43|42|   // managed memory layout is as expected
```

BTW, DateTime seems to break the sequential contract - but remember the contract is for the Marshaled memory map. There is no specification with regard to managed memory layout.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 9)]
public struct Test
{
    public DateTime dt1;
    public byte b;
}
```

And the output of above code:

```
Managed size: 12
Unmanaged size: 9
|42|0|0|0|255|63|55|244|117|40|202|43|   // finally found those 3 missing bytes :-)
```

Comment: Thank you avip, and I did realize this, it does provide another method that avoids the marshalling to a byte array, and I am doing that right now, but why isn't sequential layout with Pack=1 working as it should per the documentation?

Comment: Do you happen to have 4 chars hiding somewhere in the struct ?

Comment: No chars :) `        public Int64 int1;
        public DateTime dt1;
        public float f1;
        public float f2;
        public float f3;
        public byte b;
`

Comment: But it is a 3 byte gap :)  29 vs 32

Comment: _"Though I don't see why you should care about managed memory representation at all."_   - well I don't really, I just wanted it to be 29 bytes **for real** in order to save on space (there will be millions of these in the file). And as I pointed out in the OP it was actually writing out 32 bytes.