# Size of struct with generic type fields

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I want to estimate the size of an array of structs containing generic type parameters, in this case a dictionary entry struct. To do that I need the size of the struct.

```
struct Entry
{
   int hash;
   int next;
   TKey key;
   TValue value;
}
```

How can I get the size in bytes of this struct?

**Edit**

It seems using `Marshal.SizeOf` is problematic. Passing the *type* of the struct will raise an exception saying that the argument can't be a generic type definition.

If I instead call the overload that takes an instance, e.g. `Marshal.SizeOf(default(Entry))` it will work if *both* generic type arguments are value types. If the generic arguments are e.g. `<int, object>` then this exception is thrown

> Dictionary`2+Entry[System.Int32,System.Object]' cannot be marshaled as
>   an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

Comment: Is it even possible; surely depending on the types of `TKey` and `TValue` the size will change.

Comment: If TKey and TValue are generics, you can't now their type upfront so I don't think it's possible to calculate the size.

Comment: "size of the struct". If you work with generics, the compiler basically creates as much different structs/classes, as you use different TKey/TValue combinations. So there isn't *one* struct with *one* size, but (possibly) many differents structs each with their own individual size. So an `Entry<char, bool>` will have a different size than `Entry<string, decimal>`.

Comment: Better yet `Marshal.SizeOf(new Entry<string, decimal>())` throws an ArgumentException: "Type 'Entry`2[System.String,System.Decimal]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."

Comment: Yes, I want to get the size of the struct WITH the type known arguments, that is, at runtime.

Comment: It actually seems like a .NET error, since the exception shows that the type cannot be generic type definition. If type parameters are defined, it is clearly already not a definition. (`Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` is false.)

Comment: Read the answer by Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp

Comment: He suggests allocating N items in an array and getting the memory use and dividing by N? Surely there has to be a simpler way? Also, his answer seems to be related to the size of a class instance (not a struct) including the size of the fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like the IL [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.sizeof.aspx) instruction could be what you need. The `sizeof` instruction is used by the C# [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) operator behind-the-scenes, but the IL version has fewer restrictions for some reason.

The [ECMA CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (partition III, section 4.25) has this description of the `sizeof` instruction:

> Returns the size, in bytes, of a type. `typeTok` can be a generic
>   parameter, a reference type or a value type.
>
> For a reference type, the size returned is the size of a reference
>   value of the corresponding type, not the size of the data stored in
>   objects referred to by a reference value.
>
> [*Rationale:* The definition of a value type can change between the
>   time the CIL is generated and the time that it is loaded for
>   execution. Thus, the size of the type is not always known when the CIL
>   is generated. The `sizeof` instruction allows CIL code to determine
>   the size at runtime without the need to call into the Framework class
>   library. The computation can occur entirely at runtime or at
>   CIL-to-native-code compilation time. `sizeof` returns the total size
>   that would be occupied by each element in an array of this type –
>   including any padding the implementation chooses to add. Specifically,
>   array elements lie `sizeof` bytes apart. *end rationale*]

You should be able to get at the `sizeof` instruction with a bit of simple runtime codegen:

```
Console.WriteLine("Entry is " + TypeHelper.SizeOf(typeof(Entry)) + " bytes.");

// ...

public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static int SizeOf<T>(T? obj) where T : struct
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        return SizeOf(typeof(T?));
    }

    public static int SizeOf<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        return SizeOf(obj.GetType());
    }

    public static int SizeOf(Type t)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("t");

        return _cache.GetOrAdd(t, t2 =>
            {
                var dm = new DynamicMethod("$", typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
                ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, t2);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                var func = (Func<int>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>));
                return func();
            });
    }

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int>
        _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int>();
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't help to calculate the storage space required by a class instance; it will just give the size of the reference that would point to it (8 bytes on a 64-bit execution).

Answer (score 4):

The **approximated** size would sum of the `hash`( 4 bytes (32 bit architecture)) + `next` (4 bytes (32 bit architecture)) + `TKey` (if reference type 4 bytes for the pointer (32 bit architecture), if value type the size of that value type calculated in recursion)) + `TValue` (the same as `TKey`)

or

simply using [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx) method.

Comment: 4 bytes for the pointer? It's 2013, and you're still assuming a 32-bit architecture?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you will not beleive, but we are still using XP in corporate, so... I believe also many others too.

Comment: @Tigran can you show this with an example? I can't seem to get the sizeof/Marshal.SizeOf to work with the generic types.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: you *should* be able to do it after generic type assigment, so when *real* type is generted by calling: var runtimeType = typeof(struct_instance); and SizeOf on that type.

Comment: Yes, turns out on a struct instance it is possible, but on the struct type it is not (even if I use CreateGenericType and pass in the type args).

Comment: @AndersForsgren: because the *type* in case of generics depends on runtime type assigned to it, it's not something you cn figure out before actual asignment.

Comment: Yes, but it feels it should be possible to get the size of a struct instance (the sum of its field sizes) *at runtime* when the types are bound.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: sure, that's why I suugest to use typeof on *instance* of a struct, so you get a runtime type of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(type.TypeHandle.Value, 4)`. It returns basic instance size of the managed object. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx for more information about runtime memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

(After I wrote this, I noticed that the approach is anticipated in the *rationale* LukeH quoted)

```
struct Pin : IDisposable
{
    public GCHandle pinHandle;
    public Pin(object o) { pinHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned); }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        pinHandle.Free();
    }
}

static class ElementSize<T>
{
    private static int CalcSize(T[] testarray)
    {
      using (Pin p = new Pin(testarray))
        return (int)(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(testarray, 1).ToInt64()
                   - Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(testarray, 0).ToInt64());
    }

    static public readonly int Bytes = CalcSize(new T[2]);
}
```

I'm fairly sure that pinning and throwing away a tiny array is cheaper than dynamic compilation.  Plus a static field in a generic class is a great way to have type-safe per-type data... no need for a `ConcurrentDictionary`.