# How to get sizeof for ref struct like ReadOnlySpan?

Tags: c#

Microsoft recommends in [Write safe and efficient C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code#apply-the-in-modifier-to-readonly-struct-parameters-larger-than-systemintptrsize):

> Apply the `in` modifier to `readonly struct` parameters larger than
>   `System.IntPtr.Size`

Is there a simple way to check the managed memory size of a ref struct like `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`?

The following methods don't work:

```
// CS0208 Cannot get the size of a managed type
unsafe { size = sizeof(ReadOnlySpan<byte>); }

// CS0306 The type 'ReadOnlySpan<byte>' may not be used as a type argument
size = Marshal.SizeOf(default(ReadOnlySpan<byte>));

// ArgumentException "must not be a generic type definition"
size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ReadOnlySpan<byte>));
```

Comment: I know it's possible to estimate the size by recursively reflecting all fields and StructLayout attributes, by which I think that `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` in .NET Core 3.1 uses 16 bytes in managed memory. I don't find that method simple, though of course it's better than nothing.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167584/653473) work? It's calling `Marshal.SizeOf` on a `default(T)` "instance", where `T` would be `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

Comment: @dialer It doesn't compile because ref struct types cannot be used as type arguments for generic methods (like `Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T)`). Thanks, that's a really obvious case that I forgot to include in the question, and have now added.

Comment: @dialer Though `Marshal.SizeOf(default(ReadOnlySpan<byte>))` doesn't work, the approach you link to with `ILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.SizeOf`... **does** work. Would you write it as an answer?

Comment: Just leave it; you did the work after all /shrug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522565/1223597), the [IL sizeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.sizeof) instruction will return the managed size, even for types that [C# sizeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof) doesn't accept, including generic ref struct types like `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` and `Span<byte>`.

```
Type type = typeof(ReadOnlySpan<byte>);

var dm = new DynamicMethod("$", typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, type);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

int size = (int)dm.Invoke(null, null);
```